# fill image with another gradient image

Tags: php, image

I do not know if this is possible or not.

I have two image, one image is color gradient and another image is transparent image with texture. I want to fill up texture of second image, with the gradient image. I have searched on google and tried with same example, but did not find a solution.

Transparent texture image:

[image: Transparent texture image]

Gradient color image:

[image: Gradient color image]

Final image:

[image: final image]

Please ignore the black background of the final image.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it:

```
<?php

$img1 = imagecreatefrompng('1.png');
$img2 = imagecreatefrompng('2.png');

$imgFinal = alphaOverlay($img1, $img2, 181, 181);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($imgFinal);
imagedestroy($img1);
imagedestroy($img2);
imagedestroy($imgFinal);

function alphaOverlay($destImg, $overlayImg, $imgW, $imgH)
{
    for($y=0;$y<$imgH;$y++)
    {
        for($x=0;$x<$imgW;$x++)
        {
            $ovrARGB = imagecolorat($overlayImg, $x, $y);
            $ovrA = ($ovrARGB >> 24) << 1;
            $ovrR = $ovrARGB >> 16 & 0xFF;
            $ovrG = $ovrARGB >> 8 & 0xFF;
            $ovrB = $ovrARGB & 0xFF;

            $change = false;
            if($ovrA == 0)
            {
                $dstR = $ovrR;
                $dstG = $ovrG;
                $dstB = $ovrB;
                $change = true;
            }
            elseif($ovrA < 254)
            {
                $dstARGB = imagecolorat($destImg, $x, $y);
                $dstR = $dstARGB >> 16 & 0xFF;
                $dstG = $dstARGB >> 8 & 0xFF;
                $dstB = $dstARGB & 0xFF;

                $dstR = (($ovrR * (0xFF-$ovrA)) >> 8) + (($dstR * $ovrA) >> 8);
                $dstG = (($ovrG * (0xFF-$ovrA)) >> 8) + (($dstG * $ovrA) >> 8);
                $dstB = (($ovrB * (0xFF-$ovrA)) >> 8) + (($dstB * $ovrA) >> 8);
                $change = true;
            }
            if($change)
            {
                $dstRGB = imagecolorallocatealpha($destImg, $dstR, $dstG, $dstB, 0);
                imagesetpixel($destImg, $x, $y, $dstRGB);
            }

        }
    }
    return $destImg;
}

?>
```

outputs:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But, Sorry, your output is not my requirement. I think, you did not check final image in question, which is required output.

Comment: Yeah, he want's the exactly opposite. Changing the texture of the leaves.